# How to make a forest plot with exponential x-scale?

Tags: r, plot, scale, exponential

I am trying to plot my x-axis in the form of x^2 so that I get (1, 2, 4, 16) on my x-axis; and I would like these values to be equidistant. Does anyone know how to do this? Please let me know.

Many thanks

Comment: If you wanted an `x^2` axis, then the values 1,4,9,16,25,... would be equally spaced, no??

Answer (score 0):

If you want an x-axis where `x^2` values are equally spaced, then the tickmarks must be separated by `sqrt(x)`, so you need a sqrt transformation. Here's a way to do this using ggplot:

```
set.seed(1)    # for reprodubible example
df <- data.frame(x=1:25,y=rnorm(25))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df)+
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))+
  scale_x_sqrt(breaks=c(1,4,9,16,25))
```

[image]